# Mozilla Thunderbird: E-Mails from eBay and Kraken are blank

Tags: email, thunderbird

Since month the mails I am getting from eBay.de and Kraken.com are blank, even if I change the message view (original HTML, simple HTML or plain text). Every time the message is blank. And this only happens with eBay.de and Kraken.com (and Fidor.de, if I remember correctly).

I tried the repair function (right-click on inbox-folder -> preferences -> repair). Didn't help!

My mails are different (eBay -> bla1@web.de, Kraken -> bla2@gmail.com).

Someone from Fidor.de said one day, when I had the same problem, it might have to do something with the certificates, but I couldn't figure out, what he meat.

I really need this repaired.

Comment: The emails I get from eBay are empty, too -- but switching to one of the HTML views shows the content. -- Do you see the mail content in the message source (by pressing "Ctrl + u", or via "View → Message Source")?

Comment: You are correct. I see the eBay mails, when changing to "simple HTML" or "original HTML". Rergarding Kraken: Yes, I can view the source-code, but that doesn't help me much. For example: Confirmation links can't be copy/pasted for what ever reason. I tried it and I also deleted the breaking = in the link. It's really annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by doing following:

1. Download [MozBackup](http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/download.php)
2. Close Thunderbird
3. Start MozBackup Make a backup (only mails + passwords - nothing
   else!)
4. Deinstall Thunderbird
5. Delete the folder "Thunderbird" located in:

   - C:\Users\username\AppData\Local
   - C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming
6. Install [Thunderbird](https://www.mozilla.org/de/thunderbird/) again and close it
7. Use MozBackup and restore your mails with the backup file (*.pcv)